# What are available tools to import product tables into spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, import, spree

I need to import CSV files containing data about products that need to be migrated to spree commerce.

Is there any simple way to do this instead of trying to understand exactly the table structures of Spree ?

If not, do you any relevant documentation that explains spree data structures ? ( I find the documentation in spree web not very clear)

Thank you

Comment: which version of spree you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, please - [datashift_spree](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/datashift_spree)

Answer (score 2):

Data Shift spree is good for this. Moreover, it has a good wiki page. Follow the [wiki](https://github.com/autotelik/datashift_spree/wiki).